# App crashes when clicking on white space while reputation screen is loading

Tags: bug, android-app

Device: Moto G 2014

App version: 1.0.52

When I have a question open and then open the reputation box and while that is loading I press on the area where the tags are the app will crash.

Crash Log:

```
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709): Process: com.stackexchange.marvin, PID: 31709
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.question.QuestionHelpers$1.onClick(QuestionHelpers.java:144)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.question.QuestionHelpers$ClickableString.onClick(QuestionHelpers.java:181)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:217)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7724)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7736)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2466)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7916)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4023)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3471)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3479)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3471)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3479)
12-24 17:06:21.439 E/AndroidRuntime(31709):     at android.view.Vie
```

It also crashes when you click on a link and the reputation points are loading:

Crash log 2:

```
12-24 18:30:28.200 W/System.err(26957): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 18:30:28.206 W/System.err(26957): at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.common.PrettyWebView$1.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(PrettyWebView.java:136)
12-24 18:30:28.206 W/System.err(26957): at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:299)
12-24 18:30:28.207 W/System.err(26957): at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(AwContentsClientBridge.java:95)
12-24 18:30:28.207 W/System.err(26957): at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
12-24 18:30:28.208 W/System.err(26957): at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:24)
12-24 18:30:28.208 W/System.err(26957): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-24 18:30:28.209 W/System.err(26957): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-24 18:30:28.209 W/System.err(26957): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
12-24 18:30:28.210 W/System.err(26957): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 18:30:28.210 W/System.err(26957): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-24 18:30:28.211 W/System.err(26957): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-24 18:30:28.211 W/System.err(26957): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-24 18:30:28.212 W/System.err(26957): at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
12-24 18:30:28.213 W/System.err(26957): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Reproducible here - 1.0.51.

Comment: By 'reputation box', did you mean 'achievement dialog'? Other than that, I couldn't repro it on Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.83 (open a question, open the achievement dialog, press the tag quickly). The achievement dialog closed itself gracefully, and the app searched for the tag. Am I doing it wrong?